# How can I access a file over the network (peer-to-peer, ex: a shared folder/file) in Java?

Tags: java, file-sharing

I need to know how to access a file or folder over a network. Let's say I have a network called "work-server", and, of course, in order to access it, I would type "\\work-server\", followed by the folder or file I would like to access.

Now, I know that I can use that filepath to access the file or folder. However, let's assume that someone installs my software application and has a different server name, titled "their-work-server". I don't know the name of this server. Therefore, it is not hard-coded into the software application.

I would like to allow my software application to access the shared folder/network, without having to hard-code the server name and without requiring the user to enter the server name every time he or she runs the application.

How might I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Using what sort of network in the context of what specific code?

Comment: Thanks!

I'm trying to create a database file, but let's start smaller. Let's say I want to save a file on a computer in a workplace, such as a text file, and I want all of the computers to be able to access that text file via a shared folder. How would my software application determine how to access that network file?

Should I make each computer initially require the name of the network to access, and then save a text file on each computer, locally, with that text file, so that it can be accessed from that computer?

Comment: @Ryan by shared folder, do you mean Windows shared folder system?

Comment: Yes. For example, a computer might access the contents of the "My Documents" folder from another computer when the user enters "\\COMPUTER_TO_CONNECT_TO\Users\USER_NAME\My Documents".

Now, how would my program determine what "COMPUTER_TO_CONNECT_TO" and "USER_NAME" are?